# psql binary file missing- is there any way of replacing it without unistall/reinstall of Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've had as few issues trying to upgrade postgresql-server. I've reverted back to the older version now (9.0.3) and the service is running and accessible via pgadmin/other gui tools. 
However, I can't access it via the psql command (as user postgres). This may be possibly because the psql binary seems to be missing. I feel this may have happened when I uninstalled a version of postgres that I had intended to revert to. 
I can't reinstall version 9.0.3 because the repo is no longer valid. 
Is there any way I can install only the psql binary file and nothing else. I was considering copying the psql binary file from another server, although because the other servers have different versions of postgresql, I'm not sure if this is a good idea (?)

Answer (score 0):

I think psql binaries didn't disapear from your system.

It's just that you had symbolic links from /usr/bin to your 9.0.3 binaries.

When you installed a newer version, this links where replaced to point to the new version and when you uninstalled it, they were dropped.

Try `locate` to find your binaries. Then you would be able to recreate your symbolic links in /usr/bin.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran `locate psql` but it didn't find anything. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I meant... Are your runing on a Debian or a Red Hat based distro ?

Comment: This particular server is opensuse 11.4

Comment: Arf, not the easy one ;-)
Devrim Günduz has just released packages for SLES, you can search [there](http://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/testing/10/suse/sles-12-x86_64/)...

Comment: Or you can try getting binaries there : [https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to try 9.0.3 - you can always build it from source:

https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v9.0.3/

But many distros package pqsl-client seperate from the server and you can use a newer version of psql instead (or at least try).

There are also archives of almost any distro out there and you could fetch that single rpm/deb packge from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have 9.0.3 installed. How would I install psql-client only? When I try `zipper install postgresql` it says `postgresql-9.0.3-1.6.1.x86_64` is already installed.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162092/how-to-list-installed-files-from-a-package-in-terminal/239944

Comment: Another idea: if you have the rpm `zypper -f ` could be used to force an installation to fix a maybe corrupt installation.